# Console not showing output when I call a method that calls NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, io, nslog

When I run this code, nothing appears in the console. The print method should display the `NSLog()`'s contents, but it doesn't. This is a single view application.

Person.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject {
    int age;
    int weight;
}

-(void) print;
-(void) myAge: (int) theAge;
-(void) myWeight: (int) theWeight;

@end
```

Person.m:

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

-(void) print {
    NSLog(@"My Age is %i and my weight is %i", age, weight);
}
-(void) myAge: (int) theAge {
    age = theAge;
}
-(void) myWeight: (int) theWeight {
    weight = theWeight;
}

@end
```

main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Person.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }

    Person *Connor = [[Person alloc] init];

    [Connor myAge: 20];
    [Connor myWeight:210];
    [Connor print];

}
```

Comment: How do you know that the `print` method is actually run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `UIApplicationMain` never returns so your code after that is never run.

Move your code to before the call to `UIApplicationMain`.

Any why aren't you using properties for `age` and `weight`?

Person.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) int age;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int weight;

-(void) print;

@end
```

Person.m:

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

- (void) print {
    NSLog(@"My Age is %i and my weight is %i", self.age, self.weight);
}

@end
```

main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Person.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Person *connor = [[Person alloc] init];

        connor.age = 20;
        connor.weight = 210;
        [connor print];

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the problem, and i didn't know i could do that with properties. Still learning about them. Thanks for the tip!